# Symfony3 Forms: PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have 2 entities: Accounts and Patients:

```
class Patients
{
//..

/**
 * @var Accounts
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Accounts", mappedBy="patients")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $accounts;
 // ..
}

class Accounts {

// ...

/**
 * @var Patients
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Patients", inversedBy="accounts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patients_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $patients;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=true, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"emailValidation"})
 * @Assert\Email(groups={"emailValidation"})
 *
 */
private $email;
/// ...
}
```

I need to build a form with patients info (firstname, lastname, email) and validate it.

I did it like this:

```
class PatientsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
         // ..... 
         ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'mapped' => $options['formState'] == 'display' ? false : true,
            'property_path' => 'accounts.email',
            'data' => $options['email']
        ))
 }
       //....
       $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'formState' => 'display',
      //...
}
```

The

> 'mapped' => $options['formState'] == 'display' ? false : true,

Is an ugly workaround that I had to make because, without that I had two situations:

1.

```
->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
        'property_path' => 'accounts.email',
        'data' => $options['email']
   ))
```

Will give the following error:

> PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on,
>   but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path
>   "accounts.email" at property "email".

2. ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
       'mapped' => false,
       'property_path' => 'accounts.email',
       'data' => $options['email']
       ))

Is not taking into account the validation groups inside entities..

Is there an elegant way to validate the email inside the accounts entity?

Comment: Did I understand your question right that validation groups are not working?

Comment: Yes. The real problem is when I use  'property_path' => 'accounts.email', and I get that error: PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path "accounts.email" at property "email".

Comment: Use `->add('accounts.emai')` instead of `property_path` and make sure your `accounts` property is initialized before build the form.